# Who are all the girls fawning over Araragi?

Tags: monogatari-series

In the latest Monogatari - *Tsukimonogatari* there is a cut to an image with many young girls surrounding the protagonist.

[image]

The girls in the purple uniforms are from SHAFT's other show **Puella Magi Madoka Magica**, but who are the other girls?

Comment: he, he, Madoka is shying away and getting closer to Homura

Comment: [A dude on /a/](https://archive.moe/a/thread/119121183/#q119133609) thinks that the four middle ones are, from left to right, Machiko Ryou (Koufuku Graffiti), Kaga Ai (Zetsubou Sensei), Maekawa (Denpa Onna), and Morino Kirin (Koufuku Graffiti).

Comment: the 4 Madoka girls have matching uniforms, so they might need to be from the same series if they wear the same uniforms… or not

Comment: Kaga Ai and Maekawa are in high school, not junior high...dunno if that matters.

Comment: A actually asked a question like this on Reddit the other day. I'm rewatching the rest of Monogatari, and the inner two on the right have the same uniforms as the middle school girls he meets at the end of ep1 of Kabukimonogatari. Probably not a huge hint as to who they are though

Comment: The inner two on the right appear to be wearing the same uniform as Nadeko--witness https://calamitousintents.files.wordpress.com/2010/12/gg_bakemonogatari_-_11_e3aaf21c-mkv_snapshot_06-13_2010-12-21_12-02-20.jpg

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This answer is going to be a huge disappointment, in all sorts of ways. I genuinely hope that someone comes along and proves this answer wrong somehow.

I don't think the other four girls are references to anything; I think they're just generic middle school girls from Koyomi's hometown.

Look at the two girls on the right:

[image: girls on right]

They seem to be wearing the same school uniform as Nadeko:

[image: Nadeko in uniform]

And look at the two girls on the left:

[image: girls on left]

They appear to be wearing the uniform of Tsuganoki No. 2 Middle School, Karen-chan and Tsukihi-chan's school:

[image: Karen-chan and Tsukihi-chan in uniform]

This seems to suggest that the other four girls are just hypothetical middle school girls of the Fire Sisters' acquaintance, since they attend school in Koyomi's hometown alongside Nadeko, Karen-chan, and Tsukihi-chan. In other words, the thinking behind the scene was not, "Hey, let's fill up this scene with characters from our other works"; it was, "Hey, we've got this scene full of middle school girls, how about we shove in Madoka, Homura, Kyouko, and Sayaka?" (Poor Mami got left out again.)

However, the Madoka girls aren't actually wearing their regular uniforms either. Below we see the Mitakihara Middle School uniform, modeled by the lovely Homura, Sayaka, and Madoka:

[image: Madoka, Sayaka, Homura in uniform]

Though the ribbon is similar, their regular uniforms clearly don't have a sailor collar. Since the Madoka girls are in different uniforms, the other four girls might still be from other shows, and were put into uniforms from the Monogatari series. As a counter-argument to this, the Mitakihara uniform looks very different from Nadeko's and the Fire Sisters' uniforms; the scene would look unbalanced if the Madoka girls were put into such different-looking uniforms. Also, in the Madoka series, Kyouko doesn't attend school with the others, so it wouldn't have made sense to put her in the Mitakihara uniform. (Mami attends Mitakihara, but she got left out again.) For those reasons, the animators may have decided to give just the Madoka girls different uniforms.

None of these arguments is iron-clad, so it is still possible that the four non-magical girls are from other shows and were put into uniforms from the Monogatari series for this scene. I genuinely hope that there is some more interesting answer than this one.

Comment: hmm yeah, the fact that the inner 4 are wearing uniforms from monogatari  wheras the madoka uniforms aren't is kinda convincing with all the other info.